# webDavUrl missing from item response, why?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

webDavUrl property is not present in the list children request response.
using: GET /groups/{group-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/children

Any idea as to why that is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `webDavUrl` property must be explicity requested. Unfortunately it looks like the documentation does not mention this, so we'll need to get that rectified.

```
GET …?select=*,webDavUrl
```

Comment: Is this mentioned in any of the documentation yet?

Comment: Why is the select without $ symbol? GET …?select=*,webDavUrl works but GET …?$select=*,webDavUrl doesn't return webDavUrl

Comment: $select doesn't work due to an unfortunate interaction between Microsoft Graph, OneDrive, and OData when the wildcard (*) is provided as a selected property.